# Compiling perl >5.10 on AIX version 5.3

Tags: c, perl, aix, xlc

I've been compiling OpenSSL (and thus Perl >5.10, as it is a dependency) on multiple platforms. I've managed to get 1.1.0b compiled on every single platform except AIX, which I can't even compile Perl. I've tried several versions and looked at [the documentation Perl provides online](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlaix.html). From what I can tell, it suggests version 5.12.2.

When I attempt to compile version 5.12.2,

I take the following from the documentation, and fill in a few local system variables, such as using XLC rv7.

```
 export OBJECT_MODE=64

 ./Configure \
  -d \
  -Dcc=/usr/vac/bin/xlc_r7 \
  -Duseshrplib \
  -Duse64bitall \
  -Dprefix=`pwd`/../PERL
```

Then I attempt to make as prompted, and get the following error:

```
        /usr/vac/bin/xlc_r7 -q64 -o miniperl -brtl -bdynamic -L/usr/local/lib -b64    gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o    miniperlmain.o opmini.o perlmini.o -lbind -lnsl -ldl -lld -lm -lcrypt -lc
        LIBPATH=.../perl-5.12.2  ./miniperl -w -Ilib -MExporter -e '<?>' || make minitest
        LIBPATH=.../perl-5.12.2  ./miniperl -Ilib autodoc.pl
        /usr/bin/ln -s perl5122delta.pod pod/perldelta.pod
        LIBPATH=.../perl-5.12.2  ./miniperl -Ilib -Icpan/Cwd -Icpan/Cwd/lib pod/perlmodlib.PL -q
readdir(./../../../../..): Bad file number at lib/FindBin.pm line 116
stat(/pod/): No such file or directory at lib/FindBin.pm line 197
stat(/pod/): No such file or directory at lib/FindBin.pm line 200
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at pod/perlmodlib.PL line 9.
No such file or directory at pod/perlmodlib.PL line 19.
make: The error code from the last command is 2.
```

Taking a look at pod/perlmodlib.PL, we see the following:

```
# MANIFEST itself is Unix style filenames, so we have to assume that Unix style
# filenames will work.

open (MANIFEST, "../MANIFEST") or die $!;
```

In my desperation I tried to hack it up and avoid writing to the manifest, but then I get this issue:

```
Creating Makefile.PL in cpan/Archive-Extract for Archive::Extract

Running Makefile.PL in cpan/Archive-Extract
../../miniperl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=perl INSTALLMAN1DIR=none INSTALLMAN3DIR=none PERL_CORE=1 LIBPERL_A=libperl.a
readdir(./../../../../../../..): No such file or directory at ../../lib/File/Find.pm line 610
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at ../../lib/File/Find.pm line 773.
readdir(./../../..): No such file or directory at ../../cpan/Cwd/lib/File/Spec/Unix.pm line 483
Could not open 'lib/Archive/Extract.pm': No such file or directory at ../../cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 2588.
512 from cpan/Archive-Extract's Makefile.PL at make_ext.pl line 390.
Warning: No Makefile!
make: Cannot find a rule to create target config from dependencies.
Stop.
 make config PERL_CORE=1 LIBPERL_A=libperl.a failed, continuing anyway...
Making all in cpan/Archive-Extract
 make all PERL_CORE=1 LIBPERL_A=libperl.a
make: Cannot find a rule to create target all from dependencies.
Stop.
Unsuccessful make(cpan/Archive-Extract): code=512 at make_ext.pl line 449.
make: The error code from the last command is 2.
```

The frequency of errors makes me feel like perhaps I don't have something configured right...

My next thought was to try the most updated version, which at the time of writing is 5.24. Using the same configuration and attempting to make I get the following issue:

```
Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (you may need to install the strict module) (@INC contains: /cpan/AutoLoader/lib /dist/Carp/lib /dist/PathTools /dist/PathTools/lib /cpan/ExtUtils-Install/lib /cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib /cpan/ExtUtils-Manifest/lib /cpan/File-Path/lib /ext/re /dist/Term-ReadLine/lib /dist/Exporter/lib /ext/File-Find/lib /cpan/Text-Tabs/lib /dist/constant/lib /cpan/version/lib /lib .) at autodoc.pl line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at autodoc.pl line 25.
make: The error code from the last command is 2.
```

Which I know from other compilations means I need to edit the PERL5LIB variable.

If I keep adding all the modules to the path:

```
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/dist/Exporter/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/cpan/Text-Tabs/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/ext/re:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/dist/constant/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/dist/Carp/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/cpan/File-Path/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/dist/PathTools:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/dist/PathTools/lib:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=`pwd`/ext/File-Find/lib:$PERL5LIB
```

Even so, I'll still get an error for a module that isn't even present in the 5.24.0 source!

```
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker/version/vpp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ExtUtils::MakeMaker::version::vpp module) (@INC contains: <removed from post>) at (eval 2) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 2) line 2.
Compilation failed in require at .../perl-5.24.0/cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at .../perl-5.24.0/cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 7.
Unsuccessful Makefile.PL(cpan/Archive-Tar): code=512 at make_ext.pl line 517.
make: The error code from the last command is 2.
```

I have MakeMaker, but the 5.24 version does not contain vpp.pm! Again, in desperation I attempted to put it in there from a different source, and I get this error:

```
        LIBPATH=.../perl-5.24.0 ./miniperl -Ilib make_ext.pl cpan/Archive-Tar/pm_to_blib  MAKE="make" LIBPERL_A=libperl.a
readdir(./../../../../../../..): No such file or directory at .../perl-5.24.0/ext/File-Find/lib/File/Find.pm line 142.
Can't cd to : No such file or directory
Unsuccessful Makefile.PL(cpan/Archive-Tar): code=512 at make_ext.pl line 517.
make: The error code from the last command is 2.
```

All of this makes me feel like perhaps I'm not configuring something right... Can anyone with some experience help me out with some cut and dry installation instructions for Perl on AIX? I'd be super grateful. Thanks!

Below is some information about my system:

```
> prtconf
System Model: IBM,8231-E1D
Machine Serial Number: Not Available
Processor Type: Not Available
Processor Implementation Mode: POWER 7
Processor Version: PV_7_Compat
Number Of Processors: 0
Processor Clock Speed: Not Available
CPU Type: 64-bit
Kernel Type: 64-bit
Memory Size: 10240 MB
Good Memory Size: Not Available
Platform Firmware level: Not Available
Firmware Version: IBM,AL770_092
Console Login: disable
Auto Restart: true
Full Core: false
```

Comment: Why the C tag??

Comment: You use a C compiler, XLC rv7. It may be a problem with the compiler I'm using.

Comment: According to OpenSSL's [`NOTES.PERL`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.PERL): *"You MUST have at least Perl version 5.10.0 installed.  This minimum requirement is due to our use of regexp backslash sequence \R among other features that didn't exist in core Perl before that version."* Later in the docs it says: *"We require the minimum version [of `Test::More`] to be 0.96, which appeared in Perl 5.13.4, because that version was the first to have all the features we're using."*

Answer (score 0):

I pull down and compile openssh and openssl frequently.  I use gcc and no real magic that I can recall.

Here is my script to build it.  I don't know which perl is native to AIX but it seems to work for me.

https://github.com/pedz/aix-build-scripts/blob/master/build-scripts/build-openssl